# How to use "if"

Tags: whether-if

> If his words are true is suspicious.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
I learned "whether" can be used with "to ｰ " and "or not", but "if/that" can't do so.
I understand this rule but I wonder whether we can use "if" at the position of subject. It's because we grammatically can use "that SV -" as the subject : That I pass the exam is easy. (Basically, we
say that it is easy to pass the exam.)

Comment: No, that does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence:

> If his words are true is suspicious.

I suggest you expand the sentence. As it stands, its wording is awkward. Here are some suggestions:

1. His words may be true, but I find them suspicious.
2. I find his words to be suspicious.
3. **While** he claims his words are true, I find them suspicious.
4. **Though** he claims his words are true, I find them suspicious.
5. I suspect his words--that he claims are true--are not true.
6. I suspect his words are untrue.

If you choose to use a word that is similar in meaning to suspicious, I suggest--thanks to contributor FumbleFingers--you use the word *doubt*(or *doubtful*). For example:

- I doubt that his words are true.
- I'm doubtful his words are true.

As for starting the sentence with the "if clause," I suggest you try a different approach. You could say,

- If his words are true, well, I sincerely doubt it.

That sentence is possible, but it is unnecessarily wordy.

Comment: I'm grad for you to answer my question! I wanna know whether we can use if clause the same as whether clause at the position of subject. What do you think?

Comment: Awkward? I'd say OP's "sentence" is both ungrammatical *and* nonsensical! ***Whether** his words are true is **doubtful*** is fine, and I could *almost* (but not quite) accept ***If** his words are true is **doubtful***. But ***suspicious*** makes no sense, and ***if*** doesn't work for me in this context.

Comment: I tried to use "suspicious" like "doubtful".  I didn't know the difference between these words. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: At fumbleFingers: Thanks for the additional idea. I'll be sure to include it in the revision of my answer. Don

Comment: @HARUKA: See my revision for my opinion about the "if clause." Don